# How to use css media queries inline tag?

Tags: css, web-deployment

i have element, and this element have style, the style is auto generate from jQuery Plugin, can i do media queries inline tag?

**My Code** :

```
<div style="height: 630px;">
```

Can i do this?

```
<div style="@media(min-width:1400px;){height: 830px;}">
```

Comment: I take it you can't insert a `<style>` element in the head? Anyway, why are you giving the element a height based on the screen width? Or is that just an example? Would a height in % be a solution? At least that scales with the window...

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Anything that would require curly braces, such as media queries, pseudo-elements or pseudo-classes, can't be put in a style attribute. Only the stuff that is inbetween the curly braces.

So depending on your setup, there may not be a solution at all. Sorry.